# New webhoster redirecting me to cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi

Tags: redirect, cpanel

It's the first time that I am using a web host, and my problem is that the website redirects me to a default website page. Here is the link : `http://173.193.234.99/`

How could I fix that within CPanel ?

Comment: Add ~yourcpanel username at the end of the URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have full on access to your server? If so try uploading some files and see if you can access them. Your host name is the IP address you've got, your username and password should've been provided to you by your host.

If that still does not work I would recommend heeding the advice as seen on the page:

"If you are the owner of this website and were not expecting to see this page, please contact your hosting provider."

But again, it looks normal to me, try uploading an index.html file and see if that works.

Comment: Yes i can upload and edit files as i can edit my index.html redirect me

Comment: What is your domain name?

Comment: http://edebates.ma but thats an other problem, it doesnt redirrect to the same page but it show something else

Comment: Did you try uploading an index.html file to that page? (Edebates.ma that is)

Comment: the problem is that edebates should be refering to the 173.193.234.99 but  it doesnt, i had changed the index.html file on the public_html directory

Comment: Did you set the nameservers to those provided by the web host? If yes, did you wait 48 hours as that is how long it can take for them to propagate? If yes, when you upload an index.html file do you see it? If no, contact your web host.

Comment: Yes, it can take up to 48 hours for a DNS change to propagate.